# How to join rows in pandas dataframe based on column value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
time text
01.01.1970 abc
01.01.1970 cde
01.01.1970 fgh
01.01.1980 abc
01.01.1980 xyz
```

I would like to join the content in `text` based on column `time`. I want to join them separated by `\n`. How can I do this in order to get such a dataframe?

```
time text
01.01.1970 abc\ncde\nfgh
01.01.1980 abc\nxyz
```

I tried the following but I do not get what is expected but instead for every row in `text` I get: `text\ntime`.

```
out = (df.groupby('time', as_index=False)
       ['text'].agg(lambda x: '\n'.join(x.dropna())))
```

Comment: remove `as_index=False`.

Comment: Why your provided `groupby` doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Because there was `as_index=False` included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.groupby('time')['text'].apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep='\n'))
```

output:

```
time    text
01.01.1970  "abc\ndef"
01.01.1980  "ghi\njkl"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to drop NaNs before

```
df.dropna().groupby('time')['text'].agg('\n'.join)
```

Comment: This might not work as expected if data has other columns than the two included here. Plus, the solution is really something else.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is longer/uglier than the others but it at least gives you back a dataframe similar to your starting one.

```py
List = []
for x in df.time.unique():
    List.append([x , "\n".join(df[df.time == x].text.values)])
pd.DataFrame(List, columns = df.columns)
```